# increase partition size on CentOS 6 or move location of postfix

Tags: centos, postfix

When my host set up my server they partitioned the drives in a strange way. I have the following two file systems.

```
/dev/mapper/vg_norecordset-lv_root
/dev/mapper/vg_norecordset-lv_home
```

Unfortunately for me `...root` is only 50GB and is 100% full. `...home` still has a ton of space left. The problem is that `/var/spool/postfix/` is located in `...root` and I can't send nor receive any mails.

I think i have two options now. Move the location of postfix to the other filesystem -or- increase the size of the root partition at the cost of the home partition.

I have no idea how to do either.

`fdisk -l` output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009294e
```

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64      243202  1953001472   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_norecordset-lv_root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6527 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_norecordset-lv_swap: 4143 MB, 4143972352 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 503 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_norecordset-lv_home: 1942.0 GB, 1942038249472 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 236106 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

`pvs && vgs && lvs` output:

```
  PV         VG             Fmt  Attr PSize PFree
  /dev/sda2  vg_norecordset lvm2 a--  1.82t    0
  VG             #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  vg_norecordset   1   3   0 wz--n- 1.82t    0
  LV      VG             Attr     LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  lv_home vg_norecordset -wi-ao--  1.77t
  lv_root vg_norecordset -wi-ao-- 50.00g
  lv_swap vg_norecordset -wi-ao--  3.86g
```

Comment: Could you please add the output of `fdisk -l`, `pvs && vgs  && lvs` to your question?

Comment: @dawud I appended the information you requested to my question

Answer (score 1):

If downtime is permissible AND you have physical access AND you have a backup or don't care if this eats your data:

- reboot into single user mode (or just do telinit 1 from a shell as root)
- umount /home
- do resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_norecordset-lv_home  , Make sure this is big enough to hold all your data!!!
- i.e. resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_norecordset-lv_home 20g
- You'll be asked to do a full fsck
- do lvresize --size   /dev/mapper/vg_norecordset-lv_home
- i.e. lvresize --size 21g /dev/mapper/vg_norecordset-lv_home
- do resize2fs again without a size
- resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_norecordset-lv_home
- mount /dev/mapper/vg_norecordset-lv_home
- you'll be asked to fsck again

This should work but its from memory.  I've had to do this a bunch of times but not for a little while.

HTH